# Sharepoint 2013 Cannot delete workflow

Tags: workflow

Hello I cannot delete workflows in a site collection.

I have tried the following with no success:

-Delete from Sharepoint Designer in two different computers. Nothing happens.

-I have tried cleaning the Sharepoint Designer cache.

-Stopped the timer service and cleaned the cache.

-I have run the following Powershell script:

```
$url = "http://myserver/myurl"

$web = Get-SPWeb $url

$listToCancel = "TestPost" 

 Write-Host $web;

 $list = $web.Lists[$listToCancel] 

$tempList = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.Object]" 


 #Here the name of the list is printed
 Write-Host $list;

foreach ($wf in $list.WorkFlowAssociations) { 

   Write-Host "Nothing is printed here";
     $tempList.Add($wf); 

 } 

foreach ($wf in $tempList){ $list.RemoveWorkflowAssociation($wf); }
```

What else could I try?

Comment: The problem was that the certificate had expired.

Answer (score 0):

I had situation before that there was no WF association yet wf somehow stayed in the list. I used Sharepoint Manager to remove it. 
REF: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spm